# MPEG-DASH support on Android via NDK (C++)

Tags: android-ndk, drm, mpeg-dash

I am looking to support playing DRM into custom player which is built using NDK C++ library as plugin which decodes, converts and then perform some image processing before final presentation. In this scenario, what is the best way to support DRM (I will use NDK's Crypto and DRM interfaces) given that documentation hints at only supporting MPEG-DASH format, which is not natively supported.

Clarify if any of my assumptions are incorrect or there are simple libraries (like libdash) which can solve the problem. Extreme solution in ExoPlayer but current infrastructure is built using C++ and NDK interface to leverage hardware decoders, which excludes that as an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your image processing requires access to the raw image then unfortunately you won't (or you shouldn't!) be able to do this as encrypted video is designed to play via a secure media path which does not allow access to the raw video.

Comment: Thanks Mick, however if I want to parse MPEG-DASH then what is the best C++ library (libdash or other) that would be best suited to be integrated and leverage NDK's MediaCodec.

Comment: Well the reference library would probably be the best place to start I think: https://github.com/bitmovin/libdash